# Package Listings and use of $ and % on code R

Tags: listings, appendices, r

My code doesn't compile, what i do? The problem is on symbols `$` and `%`!

Log of errors: [link](https://cdn.rawgit.com/fsbmat/StackOverflow/master/LaTeX21.log)

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage[brazil]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{listings}
        \lstset{%
        inputencoding=utf8,
        extendedchars=true,
        literate=%
        {é}{{\'{e}}}1
        {è}{{\`{e}}}1
        {ê}{{\^{e}}}1
        {ë}{{\¨{e}}}1
        {É}{{\'{E}}}1
        {Ê}{{\^{E}}}1
        {û}{{\^{u}}}1
        {ù}{{\`{u}}}1
        {ú}{{\'{u}}}1
        {â}{{\^{a}}}1
        {à}{{\`{a}}}1
        {á}{{\'{a}}}1
        {ã}{{\~{a}}}1
        {Á}{{\'{A}}}1
        {Â}{{\^{A}}}1
        {Ã}{{\~{A}}}1
        {ç}{{\c{c}}}1
        {Ç}{{\c{C}}}1
        {õ}{{\~{o}}}1
        {ó}{{\'{o}}}1
        {ô}{{\^{o}}}1
        {Õ}{{\~{O}}}1
        {Ó}{{\'{O}}}1
        {Ô}{{\^{O}}}1
        {î}{{\^{i}}}1
        {Î}{{\^{I}}}1
        {í}{{\'{i}}}1
        {Í}{{\~{Í}}}1
}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Códigos}
\lipsum[1]

\begin{lstlisting}
    #Limpa todos os objetos na memória
    rm(list=ls())
    #Limpa o console
    cat("\014")
    set.seed(03052017)
    mu1 <- exp(as.numeric(model.matrix(~X) %*% b))
    #Vetor de médias 2
    mu2 <- exp(as.numeric(model.matrix(~W) %*% g))
    ########################################################
      IMR <- dnorm(fit1$linear.predictors)/pnorm(fit1$linear.predictors)
      #Acrescimo de IMR ao dataframe
      dt <- data.frame(dt,IMR)
      #Modelo lm(regressao multipla)
      fit2 <- lm(formula = YO~XO1+XO2+IMR, data = dt[dt$YS==1, ])
      #Geração de valores da nova covariável delta 
      delta <- (dt$IMR)*(dt$IMR+fit1$fitted.values)
      #Acrescimo de delta ao dataframe
      dt <- data.frame(dt,delta)
      #Quantidade de valores u==1
      q <- sum(u)
      #Calculo da variância
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Maybe you could help the people here to help you: *Minimize your code example to the essential part.* Do you need to use different encodings? I see **UTF8** in the listings and **latin1** (aka SO 8859-1) for the rest.

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner Decrease code and add log of errors. Thanks!

Comment: What exactly is the problem? This file compiles without errors for me.  Your error log says you have an outdated version of `listings` and you are loading a local copy that resides in the same folder as your document.  `(listings.sty
Package: listings 2002/04/01 1.0 (Carsten Heinz)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at your log file carefully you will see that the log tells you the location of each package that is loaded.  In your case there are two packages related to `listings`:

```
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\listings\lstmisc.sty"
File: lstmisc.sty 2015/06/04 1.6 (Carsten Heinz)
```

Loading this file produces the following well marked error:

```
***
*** This file requires `listings.sty' version 1.6.
*** You have a serious problem, so I'm exiting ...
***
```

If you look back to where `listings` is loaded in the log file you will see:

```
(listings.sty
Package: listings 2002/04/01 1.0 (Carsten Heinz)
```

Notice how it does not have the full file path of your MikTeX distribution (i.e., it is missing `"C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\listings`). This shows that a local copy of `listings` is being loaded, and a very old one at that.  Remove that copy (and any other local style files that should be included in your distribution) from your document folder and the document should compile properly.